# Contains doen't check in the date range

Tags: c#

I have a date range come like this,

```
string ActualReleaseDates ="7/8/2016, 7/9/2016, 7/11/2016,7/3/2016,7/10/2016,7/17/2016,7/24/2016,7/31/2016";
string NewsReleasedDate ="07/11/2016";
```

I want to check NewsReleaseDate is inside the ActualReleaseDates

But in the following code it return as a false.

```
if (ActualReleaseDates.Split(',').Contains(NewsReleasedDate.TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' })))
{
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: According to your own data it's not contained either. When looking at strings  `07/11/2016` is not the same as `7/11/2016`

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: That's presumably why there's the "TrimStart" call, although that seems like a very bad way of doing things to me, as it won't handle "07/08/2016" .

Comment: @JonSkeet then what is the betterway ?

Comment: Can u create a DateTime array instead of a string array ?

Comment: There are also spaces in the ActualReleaseDate string that are still there after the split.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, but without trimming spaces from the split the 0 trim doesn't work

Comment: You would also need to trim leading whitespace

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: Agreed. Have added an answer mentioning that, but also the bigger picture problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white space problem. You can use `trim()` and ' 7/11/2016' will be '7/11/2016'

```
    var ActualReleaseDates = "7/8/2016, 7/9/2016, 7/11/2016,7/3/2016,7/10/2016,7/17/2016,7/24/2016,7/31/2016";
    var NewsReleasedDate = "07/11/2016";

    var splitActualReleaseDates = ActualReleaseDates.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());

    if (splitActualReleaseDates.Contains(NewsReleasedDate.TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' })))
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The *immediate* problem is that after splitting your `ActualReleaseDates` string, there isn't an entry of `"7/11/2016"`... instead, there's an entry of `" 7/11/2016"`... note the space.

But more fundamentally, just trimming the start of `NewsReleasedDate` won't help if the value is something like "07/08/2016"... what you *should* be doing is handling these values as dates, rather than as strings:

- Split `ActualReleaseDates` by comma, then parse each value (after trimming whitespace) in an appropriate format (which I suspect is `M/d/yyyy`) so that you get a `List<DateTime>`.
- Parse `NewsReleasedDate` in the appropriate format, which I suspect is `MM/dd/yyyy`, so you get a `DateTime`.
- See whether the parsed value from the second step occurs in the list from the first step.

(I'd personally recommend using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) and parsing to `LocalDate` values, but I'm biased...)

Fundamentally, you're trying to see whether one *date* occurs in a list of *dates*... so make sure you get your data into its most appropriate representation as early as possible. Ideally, avoid using strings for this *at all*... we don't know where your data has come from, but if it started off in another representation and was converted *into* text, see if you can avoid that conversion.

Comment: @TechGuy: No, I'm afraid I've got *more* than enough on my plate concentrating on what I do best (language features). This conversation is now *way* off topic. I suggest we both delete our comments here...

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq to convert your strings into DateTime objects and compare them instead of strings

```
string ActualReleaseDates ="7/8/2016,7/9/2016,7/11/2016,7/3/2016,7/10/2016,7/17/2016,7/24/2016,7/31/2016";
string NewsReleasedDate ="07/11/2016";

var releaseDates = ActualReleaseDates.Split(',').Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x));
var newsReleased = DateTime.Parse(NewsReleaseDate);

if (releaseDates.Contains(newsReleased))
{
    //some code here
}
```

please note that DateTime is parsed respectively to the current Culture. You can use DateTime.ParseExact if you want to specify exact date format.

Answer (score 1):

You can Prase to DateTime before doing the query like this:

**(I think this is the most accurate and guaranteed way to compare dates)**

```
Func<string, DateTime> stringToDate = s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.Trim(), "M/d/yyyy", 
                                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime newReleaseDateTime = stringToDate(NewsReleasedDate);

bool result = ActualReleaseDates.Split(',').Select(x => stringToDate(x))
                                            .Contains(newReleaseDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns false because of the date 07/11/2016 stored in NewsReleasedDate is stored as string with a '0' at the begining. And in the ActualReleaseDates string you have white spaces between the ',' and numbers.

Try to rewrite theese strings like this :

```
ActualReleaseDates ="7/8/2016,7/9/2016,7/11/2016,7/3/2016,7/10/2016,7/17/2016,7/24/2016,7/31/2016"; // white spaces removed.
```

and the variable like this :

```
NewsReleasedDate ="7/11/2016"; // 0 removed
```

This is my code example :

```
 string ActualReleaseDates = "7/8/2016,7/9/2016,7/11/2016,7/3/2016,7/10/2016,7/17/2016,7/24/2016,7/31/2016";
 string NewsReleasedDate = "7/11/2016";
 string[] dates = ActualReleaseDates.Split(',');
 Console.WriteLine(dates.Contains(NewsReleasedDate));
```

This is not the best way to compare dates, you can use Date class which is usefull to do this kind of comparations.